# Reading Mac data of Zigbee

Tags: c++, c, embedded, zigbee, home-automation

Iam working on a project using one of the popular Zigbee based RF-MCU Mac-codebases.I have integrated a sensor to the MCU and the same is reading data and iam sending data to the gateway using the Zigbee protocol stack.I was trying to read data coming from Mac layer in the network layer.Are there functions/API's to do it?

Any links or books would do a lot of good.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is too broad for StackOverflow - maybe try one of the other StackExchange sites?

Comment: @vikramls - the question **does not** seek to find a library, it asks if the software **named in the question** has a particular capability.

Comment: Please provide more details.  What hardware are you using?  What ZigBee stack?  Which ZigBee profile?  Which cluster/attribute are you using?  What kind of gateway?  Have you tried sample programs from the platform you're using?  If you're going to use ZigBee, then your code should be running at the application layer, using the ZigBee Cluster Library (ZCL) to read/write attributes.

Comment: Iam using a CC2538dk Zstack HA profile IAS Zone/0x0500,i tried running example programs its runs nicely no issues with that, but my Q stresses more about the packet read API's from Mac in NW layer as i wanna modify the stack a bit

Comment: Guess the Zstack is Zigbee Pro